# Docker Windows getting Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers for any pull image command or login

Tags: windows, docker, proxy

When trying to run `docker run hello-world` on windows 10(no option), I am getting this error(a common error I saw on many threads) :

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
```

I already had some images pulled earlier(couple of months back) which are working. But I am not able to pull any new image(eg: mongo) or even not able to pull hello-world image. Have searched throughout, tried setting up dns to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4, experimental=true inside docker configs(Docker Desktop GUI), yet unable to resolve. One thing I wasn't expecting was HTTP PROXY inside docker info, as I had removed the proxy settings from docker's GUI and even environment variables.

docker info:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.3.4)

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 2
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.39-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.941GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: <Docker Id>
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http://<ip>:port/
 HTTPS Proxy: http://<ip>:port/
 No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.2,firm.com,firm.org
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Can someone please help how to remove these proxies from docker info and allow me to pull the images ?
I have not ticked `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` and `Use the WSL 2 based engine` inside docker-desktop gui. Also inside proxies, setting manual is turned off and network uses manual dns configuration of 8.8.8.8. Also I am unable to ping to hub.docker.com which says request timeout, and trying to do docker login inside cmd returns the same request timeout error, but docker desktop(GUI) is showing my user logged in. I feel if we are able to remove the proxy from docker info, it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently solved it with this change:

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

This is weird stuff according to me since we are disabling the manual proxy configs it shouldn't go inside it, but even after restarting and stopping the services it didn't work. So eventually I removed all the proxy url(despite manual proxy being off) and then it worked. Just windows stuff I guess.